soap xml response xsi:type value changed
Our tomcat webservice response is soap xml format.
The xsi:type change from xsi:type="ax235:SearchOutput"> to xsi:type="ax239:SearchOutput">
one day suddenly.
The ns return is as below:
previously:
<ns:return
                xmlns:ax236="http://vo.ws.org/xsd"
                xmlns:ax235="http://output.vo.ws.org/xsd"
                xmlns:ax232="http://service.query.org/xsd"
                xmlns:ax230="http://service.w3.org/xsd"
                xmlns:ax229="http://service.ws.org/xsd"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                xsi:type="ax235:SearchOutput">
                <ax235:batchId xsi:nil="true" />
                <ax235:status_code>000000001</ax235:status_code>

Now:
<ns:return 
                xmlns:ax236='http://service.query.org/xsd' 
                xmlns:ax234='http://service.w3.org/xsd' 
                xmlns:ax233='http://service.ws.org/xsd' 
                xmlns:ax240='http://vo.ws.org/xsd' 
                xmlns:ax239='http://output.vo.ws.org/xsd' 
                xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' 
                xsi:type='ax239:SearchOutput'>
            <ax239:batchId xsi:nil='true'></ax239:batchId>
            <ax239:status_code>000000001</ax239:status_code>

Can someone help to analysis what caused this xsi:type value change?
This may caused by upgrade of axis or soap version upgrade.

The only thing that changed is the namespace prefix binding :

ax235 prefix is bound to 'http://output.vo.ws.org/xsd' namespace before the upgrade
ax239 prefix is bound to 'http://output.vo.ws.org/xsd' namespace after the upgrade

So the response is just the same, except that the prefix changed.

yes, the response is same, just the prefix changed, do you know why the prefix changed?

we didn't do any change of the code, the response prefix don't change for 2 years, it changed suddenly one day, we need to know the reason.Thanks!

It may be related to regeneration of sources from WSDL or something like this. If you want to fix namespace prefix, you can define them using a XJC plugin like JAXB - Namespace Prefix Plugin or do the equivalent in code
